# Using multi-indexes as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the index is a multi-index of `start` and `end` values. If these were regular columns, I could just do

`df["End"] - df["Start"]`

However, since these rows are multi-indexes I get the error `KeyError: 'End'` when I try this.

I could do a for-loop over the values I get from `df.index.get_values()` to add each `start` and `end` to their own list and make a dataframe from that, but this is very un-pandaish and slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html#pandas.Index.get_level_values) will get the index values at a given level.

so, in your case:

```
df.index.get_level_values('End') - df.index.get_level_values('Start')
```